# StackExchange account reset?

Tags: discussion, support, accounts

It just got reset. No idea.
Also, im using few content here beacuse stupid errors.

Sorry, i could not post on the meta beacuse the account reputation was reset to 1, which is not enough reputation to post. Like if you want to make me allow to post on meta.

Comment: What was your previous account name? Can you find it in the users list on SO or other sites?

Comment: I dont know how i find it and it was the same as i had. I logged with google, And yesterday IT WAS WITH GOOGLE TOO.

Comment: Did you post any questions/answers that you could find again?

Comment: Are you sure you logged in with the _same_ email/gmail address/account?

Comment: My last post was 1 day ago. It also doesn't show my old posts at all, bart.       Oded, Yes. i got no typos.

Comment: You can post with 1 rep. Were you banned?

Comment: Not on meta websites, i posted on stackoverflow then it moved to meta, juergen d.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts. BTW you are on a meta site with 1 rep and posted

Comment: @juergend wrong meta.  MSE only requires 1 rep.  MSO and other child meta require 5.

Comment: @NunoLava1998 there are multiple login options.  Stack Exchange supports OpenId and OAuth2, so your account is tied to a login via an external provider of one of those standards.  If you originally signed up using Google or Facebook, then tried to create a Stack Exchange login with the same credentials, you would have created a new account, not logged into your old account.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28276720/2958086 This is you?

Comment: @Oded From what I can tell regarding the post I found, his account got deleted/disassociated. I doubt it's user error at this point unless there's a way to manually nuke your own account.

Comment: @Compass - new accounts can be self deleted (under some restrictions - if they have upvoted content and have voted themselves they would be not be able to self delete). There is also 24 hour waiting period.

Comment: @Oded Well, I have no idea then. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28276598/timeline/ The timeline indicates an upvote within half an hour of the answer, so would that have stopped a self delete?

Comment: Not sure one upvote is enough, @Compass.

Answer (score 12):

[Our terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) require users to be at least 13 years of age. Since you admitted to being... less than that... I had to delete your account. I *did* send you an email about this...

And now I have to delete this one too.

[I'm so, so sorry.](https://nevillesremembrall.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/10-im-so-sorry.gif)